# very slow TTFB in 10% of cases

Tags: apache, cakephp, pagespeed, ddos

So I am hosting couple of websites on Apache server (centOS7). I have Google's pagespeed enabled and most of my pages load in around 1 second which is great. Yet sometimes (1 out of 10 cases) it takes extremely long to load the homepage. It seems to happened with homepage most of the time and for in example TTFB takes 50 seconds and the rest of the content less than 0.5 second. When the homepage finally loads, all content pages load very fast. There is no errors in the logs. Pages are written in cakephp and using mysql.

I already tried to run

```
     netstat -tuna | grep :80 | grep SYN_RECV
```

To see if Im not a victim of DoS/DDoS attack but I never get more than 2 or 3 results from that call. 
Moreover, sometimes the content pages load very fast but then there is half of an image not loaded on a page that has around 20 images so the browser spins. After around a minute that half of an image finishes loading.

Thats my pagespeed config:

```
  ModPagespeedRewriteLevel CoreFilters
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters prioritize_critical_css
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_javascript
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters sprite_images
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_png_to_jpeg,convert_jpeg_to_webp
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace,remove_comments
  ModPagespeedDisableFilters combine_css
  ModPagespeedDisableFilters inline_css
```

Any ideas on how to find the solution?

Comment: For info: 1 second is not great. You need to profile your application, and identify something specific to investigate. i.e. is it 50 seconds of php time? That's the first thing to confirm (it probably is). Don't look at your server setup until you've eliminated the most obvious cause (the app code).

Comment: My first guess was server configuration because that ridiculous 50 seconds happens around every 10-15th page. Sometimes it is even hard to repeat that behavior because it loads right away many times in a row. What do you mean by profiling my application?

Comment: [google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+profiler) - http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant install this profiler since all of the sites are in production right now and I cant afford to have a downtime.

Comment: "this profiler" - well, I'd start with logging the time a request starts and ends. You don't need magic for that just put `define('START', time()` in e.g. your webroot index. and then in the code `$elapsed = time() - START; log $elapsed somewhere etc.` - you've come to SO prematurely IMO. You know there's _a_ problem (maybe) but you can't yet confirm where in your stack the problem is - or even if it's network related.